# Unable to remove dependency from gradle

Tags: android, gradle, androidx

I'm trying to exclude a dependency from my Android project but I can't. The reason why I'm trying to do this is mainly because I will build this project as an apk and I don't want to have these gradle's dependency.

So, the dependency I need to exclude is  -> androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1.

In ran this command (./gradlew :app:internal:dependencies --configuration releaseRuntimeClasspath)to see the dependency tree.

```
+--- project :utils
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.databinding:databinding-common:7.4.2
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:7.4.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.databinding:databinding-adapters:7.4.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.databinding:databinding-ktx:7.4.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- project :logger:public
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.22 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- project :legacy:model:core (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- project :others:io
|    |    |    |    |    +--- project :others:io:files
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.22 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- project :others:bytes
|    |    |    |    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.22 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.22 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- project :others:bytes (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- project :others:bytes (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1
|    |    |    |    +--- io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.5.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.5.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.5.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0 -> 1.7.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.8.0 -> 1.9.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.3.1 -> 2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.6.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0 -> 1.9.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.9.0 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0 -> 2.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate-ktx:1.2.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller:1.3.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.tracing:tracing:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.2 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.6.0 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.1.0 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0 -> 1.1.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.2.0 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |         +--- androidx.core:core:1.3.0 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |         \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.2.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.3.0 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.1 -> 2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.0.0 -> 1.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.2.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.3.0 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6 -> 1.6.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.activity:activity:1.7.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.0.0 -> 1.3.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0 -> 2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0 -> 2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller:1.3.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.5.1 -> 2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1 -> 2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.resourceinspection:resourceinspection-annotation:1.0.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.0 -> 1.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.activity:activity:1.7.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate-ktx:1.2.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.activity:activity:1.7.2 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.5.1 -> 1.7.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection-ktx:1.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.20 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx:2.6.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate-ktx:1.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.6.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 -> 1.7.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.6.1 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.22 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.2.0 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> 1.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.2.0 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> 1.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.2
|    |    |    |    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- io.github.binaryfoo:emv-bertlv:0.1.8 (*)
```

And in this is the module's buld gradle ( :utils ) where I'm not able to exclude the dependency ->

```
apply from: "../common-android-library-config.gradle"
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply from: '../maven-publication.gradle'

android {

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'androidx.appcompat', module:'appcompat'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
        }

        development {
            debuggable false
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
        }
        
    }
}

dependencies {

    //testing
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$testRunnerVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$jUnitVersion"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockitoCoreVesion"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:$mockitoInlineVersion"
    testImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:$mockitoKotlinVersion"
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$archCoreTestingVersion"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$kotlinCoroutinesTestVersion"


    //android x
    compileOnly ("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activityKtxVersion")


    //gson
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gsonVersion"

    //joda
    compileOnly "net.danlew:android.joda:2.10.7.2"

    //koin
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-core:$koinVersion"
    
    // HERE WHERE IM TRYING TO EXCLUDE
    implementation ("io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koinVersion"){
        exclude group: 'androidx.appcompat', module: 'appcompat'
    }
    
    compileOnly "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompatVersion"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlinStdlibJdk7Version"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$locationVersion"

    implementation "io.github.binaryfoo:emv-bertlv:$emvBerTlvVersion"
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use exclude block like this -

example:  `exclude group: 'androidx.appcompat', module: 'appcompat'`

Dependency implementation of your gradle file will look like this-

```
implementation ('androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1') {
    exclude group: 'androidx.appcompat', module: 'appcompat'
.....rest of code
```

Comment: Thanks, but i´m doing exactly that and it does not work.